# Verification of Email Addresses from MX using Bash

Tags: bash, email, unix, smtp, telnet

I want to verify a batch of email addresses in a file (say .txt) using telnet to mx and declaring recipient then checking response.
I need a script that reads email addresses from a file, takes out host after '@', looks up MX, telnets(or mailcmd, whichever you prefer), does the deed, then outputs result in 2 files (valid and invalid)

YES I have searched before posting and a few answers were close but I am a noob at bash and modifying them to suit my needs was not possible for me.

Please help!

PS: Below is what I found but I don't know how to pass email addresses to it, and also it is fixed with a single MX.

```html
#!/bin/bash
# check for valid usage
if [ x$1 = 'x' ]
then
echo "Usage: $0 <email address>"
exit 1
fi

# grabbing fields
user=`echo $1 | cut -f1 -d\@`
host=`echo $1 | cut -f2 -d\@`
mxhost=`host -t mx $host | cut -f7 -d\ `
len=`echo $mxhost | wc -c`
len=`expr $len - 2`
mxhost=`echo $mxhost | cut -b1 -$len`

# compose email commands
echo -ne "helo test.com\r\n" > mailcmd
echo -ne "mail from: test\@test.com\r\n" >> mailcmd
echo -ne "rcpt to: $1\r\n" >> mailcmd
echo -ne "quit\r\n" >> mailcmd

# check for mail results
mailresult=`cat mailcmd | nc $mxhost 25| grep ^550 | wc -c`

if [ $mailresult -eq 0 ]
then
echo $1 "is valid"
exit 0
else
echo $1 "is not valid"
exit 1
fi

# clean up
rm mailcmd
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?